# How to copy array to file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I read array from the text file and I want to copy this array's elements to another text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
    int numbers[ ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "1. before opening file\n";

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("test.txt");    

    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "error opening input file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "2. after opening file\n";
    cout << "3. before reading file, count = " << count << '\n';

    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers [ count])
        count++;

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "4. after reading file, count = " << count << '\n';
    cout<< "The numbers are : ";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout<< endl;

    cout << "5. Program ending" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I added this code but it doesn't work. How can I copy this array's elements to destination.txt file?

```
ofstream fstreamFile("destination.txt");
    copy(
         numbers,
         numbers + sizeof(numbers),
         ostream_iterator<int>(fstreamFile)
         );
```

my elements are 10,20,30,40 but in the destination.txt file, output is "10203040160641613632767-1973944304-...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `sizeof` for the end "iterator" of the array.

The `sizeof` operator returns the size *in **bytes***, not in array elements.  That means you will go way out of bounds beyond the end of the array.

I suggest you change to use the standard [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) helper functions to get the "iterators" for the array:

```
std::copy(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), ...);
```

For proper arrays (but not for pointers, and remember that arrays decays to pointers very easily) those functions will do the right thing.

Comment: thank you, it solved my issue.

Comment: @hbakan If it did, then consider marking it as "accepted"